# Multi-intent natural language processing and classification

Tags: python, python-3.6, nlp

So, I'm making my own home assistant and I'm trying to make a multi-intent classification system. However, I cannot find a way to split the query said by the user into the multiple different intents in the query.

For example:

```
I have my data for one of my intents (same format for all) 

{"intent_name": "music.off" , "examples": ["turn off the music" , "kill 
the music" , "cut the music"]}
```

and the query said by the user would be:

`'dim the lights, cut the music and play Black Mirror on tv'`

I want to split the sentence into their individual intents such as :

`['dim the lights', 'cut the music', 'play black mirror on tv']`

however, I can't just use `re.split` on the sentence with `and` and `,` as delimiters to split with as if the user asks :

`'turn the lights off in the living room, dining room, kitchen and bedroom'`

this will be split into

`['turn the lights off in the living room', 'kitchen', 'dining room', 'bedroom']`

which would not be usable with my intent detection

this is my problem, thank you in advance

### UPDATE

okay so I've got this far with my code, it can get the examples from my data and identify the different intents inside as I wished however it is not splitting the parts of the original query into their individual intents and is just matching.

```
import nltk
import spacy
import os
import json
#import difflib
#import substring
#import re
#from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches
#from fuzzywuzzy import process

text = "dim the lights, shut down the music and play White Collar"

commands = []

def get_matches():

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./data"):  

        for filename in files:

            f = open(f"./data/{filename}" , "r")
            file_ = f.read()
            data = json.loads(file_)

            choices.append(data["examples"])

        for set_ in choices:

            command = process.extract(text, set_ , limit=1)

            commands.append(command)

    print(f"all commands : {commands}")
```

this returns `[('dim the lights') , ('turn off the music') , ('play Black Mirror')]` which is the correct intents but I have no way of knowing which part of the query relates to each intent - this is the main problem

my data is as follows , very simple for now until I figure out a method:

`play.json`

`{"intent_name": "play.device" , "examples" : ["play Black Mirror" , "play Netflix on tv" , "can you please stream Stranger Things"]}`

---

`music.json`

`{"intent_name": "music.off" , "examples": ["turn off the music" , "cut the music" , "kill the music"]}`

---

`lights.json`

`{"intent_name": "lights.dim" , "examples" : ["dim the lights" , "turn down the lights" , "lower the brightness"]}`

Comment: sounds like partially a tokenisation problem. you would use `spacy` or `nltk` for that. will be better than just a call to `split`. You need to have some relations for intents to map to a single item.

Comment: what do you mean , relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing two problems in your questions:

1. Multiple independent intents within a single query (e.g. `shut down the music and play White Collar`)
2. Multiple *slots* (using the form-filling framework) within a single intent (e.g. `turn the lights off in the living room bedroom and kitchen`).

These problems are quite different. Both, however, can be formulated as word tagging problem (similar to POS-tagging) and solved with machine learning (e.g. CRF or bi-LSTM over pretrained word embeddings, predicting label for each word).

The intent labels for each word can be created using BIO notation, e.g.

```
shut   B-music_off
down   I-music_off
the    I-music_off
music  I-music_off
and    O
play   B-tv_on
White  I-tv_on
Collar I-tv_on

turn    B-light_off
the     I-light-off
lights  I-light-off 
off     I-light-off
in      I-light-off
the     I-light-off
living  I-light-off
room    I-light-off
bedroom I-light-off
and     I-light-off
kitchen I-light-off
```

The model would read the sentence and predict the labels. It should be trained on at least hundreds of examples - you have to generate or mine them.

After splitting intents with model trained on such labels, you will have short texts corresponding to a unique intent each. Then for each short text you need to run the second segmentation, looking for slots. E.g. the sentence about the light can be presented as

```
turn    B-action
the     I-action
lights  I-action
off     I-action
in      O
the     B-place
living  I-place
room    I-place
bedroom B-place
and     O
kitchen B-place
```

Now the BIO markup hepls much: `the B-place` tag separates `bedroom` from `the living room`.

Both segmentations can in principle be performed by one hierarchical end-to-end model (google semantic parsing if you want it), but I feel that two simpler taggers can work as well.

Comment: thanks David for such clear presentation. Would it be needed to tag every sentence in BIO notation for tasks at hand to train a model on custom dataset? Is there some open source implementation for creating a model on custom data set!